# Numerical Solution of Fredholm Integral Equation Using Bernstein Polynomials

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning, integral-equations

I'm  trying  to solve a Integral equation:

$$y(x)-\int_{-1}^1 \left(x^4-t^4\right) y(t) \, dt=x$$

for `n > 5` my code is very slow.

**How to speed up?**

Example 2 from this [Paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1309/1309.6311.pdf)  exact solution is `y[x]=x`.

```
 n = 3;
 a1 = -1;
 b1 = 1;
 B[x_, i_] := Binomial[n, i]*((x - a1)^i*(b1 - x)^(n - i))/(b1 - a1)^n
 k[t_, x_] := (x^4 - t^4);
 a[x_] := 1;
 f[x_] := x;
 λ = 1;

 K2[x_, j_] := Integrate[B[x, j]*f[x], {x, a1, b1}];
 K3[j_, i_] := Integrate[(a[x]*B[x, i] - Integrate[λ*k[t, x]*B[t, i], {t, a1, b1}])*B[x, j], {x, a1, b1}];

 sol = Table[Total@Table[M[i]*K3[j, i], {i, 0, n}] == K2[x, j], {j, 0, n}];
 func = Sum[M[i]*B[x, i], {i, 0, n}] /. Solve[sol, Table[M[i], {i, 0, n}]][[1]] // Simplify
 Plot[{x, func}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's those `Integrate`s that slow down the calculation, let's turn to `NIntegrate` with `Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}`:

```
n = 3;
a1 = -1;
b1 = 1;
B[x_, i_] := Binomial[n, i] ((x - a1)^i (b1 - x)^(n - i))/(b1 - a1)^n
k[t_, x_] := (x^4 - t^4);
a[x_] := 1;
f[x_] := x;
λ = 1;

nIntegrate[most__] := NIntegrate[most, Method -> {Automatic, SymbolicProcessing -> 0}]

K2[j_?NumericQ] := nIntegrate[B[x, j] f[x], {x, a1, b1}]

mid[x_?NumericQ, i_?NumericQ] := nIntegrate[λ k[t, x] B[t, i], {t, a1, b1}]

K3[j_?NumericQ, i_?NumericQ] := 
  nIntegrate[(a[x] B[x, i] - mid[x, i]) B[x, j], {x, a1, b1}];

sol = Table[Total@Table[M[i] K3[j, i], {i, 0, n}] == K2[j], {j, 0, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.577445, Null} *)
func = Sum[M[i] B[x, i], {i, 0, n}] /. Solve[sol, Table[M[i], {i, 0, n}]][[1]] // 
  Simplify
(* -8.32667*10^-17 + 1. x - 1.66533*10^-16 x^2 + 2.08167*10^-15 x^3 *)
```

Though some warnings pop up, the result is accurate enough, I think.